Movie about temple run by women
This sounds a bit crazy, but back in the 90s as a child, I saw a movie (at least twice) that had roughly this plot:
There was a temple or castle/fortress that only women were permitted to enter. There was something important and special inside that was vital for the world or something (magical thing, possibly shining and blue). The temple was invaded at the start, the women inside were killed, a few survived. I think the woman leading the attack was a former follower who turned rogue.
A plucky young female adept was given the task of finding said magical item and had to bring it back in time to save the world/temple.  She met some young guy who helped her get the item and learn some important lesson, trust men or love or some trope like that.
The movie itself might be from earlier than the 90s.

can you add anything else? like region? language? medium? studio? actors/actresses? anything else that can shed more light on this?

It was in English. Definetly a movie and not a tv series. I'm pretty sure it was american made.

It appears that @ghoti may have found what you were looking for, enjoy.

You are thinking of:
Red Sonja (1985)

Comparing an IMDb plot summary to your question:

After her family is murdered a young woman [A plucky young female] named Red Sonja becomes a master of the sword [adept] and seeks revenge on the evil queen responsible for the mayhem that has befallen her. Also, it seems the queen has stolen a powerful, carefully guarded, glowing orb right before it was meant to be destroyed, one that has powers of its' own, allowing for the possessor to control elemental forces and call down storms and earthquakes, if they so wish. Kalidor, one of the individuals in place to oversee the destruction of the orb, joins forces with Red Sonja, as their paths may differ, but they ultimately lead to the same place. An impudent, young prince named Tarn and his guard/manservant Falkon, whose kingdom was unceremoniously wiped out by Gerden as a test for her newfound powers, soon joins them.


Comparing another IMDb plot summary to your question:

The tyrant Gedren seeks the total power in a world of barbarism. She attacks and kills the keepers of a powerful talisman just before it is destroyed. Gedren then uses the power of the talisman in her raid of the city Hablac. Red Sonja, sister of the keeper, sets out with her magic sword to overthrow Gedren. The talisman's master Kalidor follows to protect her. Of course they fall in love [ She met some young guy who helped her get the item and learn some important lesson, trust men or love or some trope like that] - however Red Sonja's power bases on the oath to never give herself to any man...


Comparing the plot in the Wikipedia article for "Red Sonja (film)" to your question:

Varna is a member of an order of priestesses [There was a temple or castle/fortress that only women were permitted to enter.] who were preparing to destroy a light-powered relic known as the Talisman that created the world and whose growing power now threatens it [There was something important and special inside that was vital for the world or something (magical thing, possibly shining and blue).]. However, Gedren's army and her aide-de-camp Ikol slaughtered the priestesses [The temple was invaded at the start, the women inside were killed, a few survived. I think the woman leading the attack was a former follower who turned rogue.] and took the Talisman while Varna was fatally wounded by the time she found Kalidor. Before dying, Varna tells Sonja of the events at her temple while urging her to find the Talisman and destroy it [was given the task of finding said magical item and had to bring it back in time to save the world/temple].




Some of these picture are a bit familiar, I think this is it. Thanks everyone.
